# Jelastic cloud configuration review

Tags: cloud, jelastic

There are a lot of tools like NCC Scout which can be used to do a comprehensive cloud configuration review required to complete the Facebook Data Protection Assessment.

Unfortunately, most of those tools support only the big cloud guys like amazon,google...etc

Is there such a service for Jelastic cloud?